# Flutter Error: The getter 'iterator' was called on null - I'm using FutureBuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, null, firebase-storage, flutter-futurebuilder

i'm trying to fetch data/images from **firebase storage** and then put them into ImageSlider using **FutureBuilder**, i've succeed to add into list but fail to pass into futurebuilder. Please if know what i should do to make it right, i will be happy for your contribution.

Note: after future builder then i put the images into provider, if you have any suggestion of what i may use instead of provider so that when the user want to review again the product images, user can view images without reloading the same product images.

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kariakoonline/constants.dart';
import 'package:kariakoonline/models/product_images.dart';
import 'package:kariakoonline/provider/productImages_provider.dart';
import 'package:kariakoonline/provider/product_provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;

class ProductImages extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProductImages({
    Key key,
    @required this.product,
    this.sellerId,
    this.productId,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String product;
  final String sellerId;
  final String productId;

  @override
  _ProductImagesState createState() => _ProductImagesState();
}

class _ProductImagesState extends State<ProductImages> {
  int selectedImage = 0;
  ProductImagesModel imgModel = ProductImagesModel();
  List<ProductImagesModel> listPic = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    print(
        'id:${widget.product} - productId: ${widget.productId} and Seller: ${widget.sellerId}');
    // listProductImages();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> listProductImages() async {
    List<ProductImagesModel> url = [];
    List<String> images = [];
    String imgUrl;
    firebase_storage.ListResult result = await firebase_storage
        .FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref('product_images/${widget.sellerId}/${widget.productId}')
        .listAll();
    if (result.items != null) {
      for (firebase_storage.Reference ref in result.items) {
        imgUrl = await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref(ref.fullPath)
            .getDownloadURL();
        if (imgUrl != null) {
          images.add(imgUrl);
        }
      }
      final imgUrlMode = imgModel.copy(id: widget.product, image: images);
      url.add(imgUrlMode);
      print('images: $images');
      print('img url mode: ${imgUrlMode.image}');
      print('url $url');
    }
    return url;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: listProductImages(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final imgProvider = Provider.of<ProductImagesProvider>(context);
          final providerImg = imgProvider.productImg;
          imgProvider.setProductImg(snapshot.data);
          print('My Data:');
          print('My Data: ${snapshot.data}');
          print('Provider Model IMG Length: ${imgProvider.productImg.length}');
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text('Something is wrong. Try again letter'),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text('Error Occoured. Try again letter'),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }

          return Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 1,
                    child: CarouselSlider(
                      options: CarouselOptions(
                        disableCenter: true,
                        onScrolled: (index) {},
                      ),
                      items: <Widget>[
                        ...List.generate(
                          providerImg.length,
                          (index) => CachedNetworkImage(
                            imageUrl: providerImg[index].image[selectedImage],
                            imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: imageProvider,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                              child: Center(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                              ),
                            ),
                            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Stack(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    'assets/images/placeholder.jpg',
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Center(
                                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ...List.generate(
                      providerImg.length,
                      (index) => buildSmallPreview(index),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  GestureDetector buildSmallPreview(int index) {
    final productData = Provider.of<KariakooProducts>(context, listen: false);
    final specDataById = productData.findProductId(widget.product);
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          selectedImage = index;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 40,
        width: 40,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          border: Border.all(
              color: selectedImage == index ? kPrimaryColor : kSecondaryColor),
        ),
        child: Image.network(
          '',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: First thing I would try is changing `listProductImages` signature to return a `Future<List<ProductImagesModel>>` instead of a `Future<void>`.

Comment: i've tried to put both 'Future<List>' and 'Future<List<ProductImageModel>>' but it still give me an error *(The getter 'iterator' was called on null)* @EmilWalser

Comment: Add the code for the various places you're using the `Provider`.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution.
Started by declaring

```
 Future<List<ProductImagesModel>> listPic;
```

Then i initiated the listPic from the Future Function listProductImages()

```
 @override
 void initState() {
 listPic = listProductImages();
 super.initState();
 }
```

Then i call listPic in FutureBuilder

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return FutureBuilder(
    future: listPic,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
  ......
  ......
```